# simplexml_load_file não retorna nenhum registro

Tags: xml, foreach

tenho a seguinte rotina para leitura de arquivo XML:

```
    $arquivo_geral = "xml_categ_1.xml";
    if (file_exists($arquivo_geral)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivo_geral);
        foreach($xml->categoria as $categoria):
            $idcat  = $categoria->id;
            $tipo   = $categoria->tipo;
            $categ  = trim($categoria->categ);
            $status = $categoria->status;

            echo $categ . "<br>";
        endforeach;
    } else {
        echo "Arquivo " . $arquivo_geral . " não encontrado...";
        exit();
    }
```

O arquivo XML lido é o seguinte:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <categoria>
        <id>1</id>
        <tipo>D</tipo>
        <categ>CATEGORIA</categ>
        <status>I</status>
    </categoria>
```

O problema é que não aparece o registro lido. O arquivo existe, o print_r($xml), mostra o seguinte:

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object ( [id] => 1 [tipo] => D [categ] => CATEGORIA [status] => I )
```

O curioso é que uso a mesma maneira em outra rotina para ler outros arquivos XML e lá funciona.
Alguém tem um dica do que pode ser ?
Obrigado.